# How to rewrite polynomial as linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I got the polynomial $p(\lambda) = (2-\lambda)^3\cdot(4-\lambda)-4\cdot(2-\lambda)^2$.
How can I rewrite it as linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_5$? I know I have to find the roots (they are $2$ and $3$), but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: $p(\lambda )=(2-\lambda )^2\big((2-\lambda )(4-\lambda )-4\big).$ Now find all roots of $(2-\lambda )(4-\lambda )-4$ in $\mathbb F_5$.